# Problems with C::B compiler configuration

Tags: visual-c++, mingw, codeblocks

I configured MinGW to Code::Blocks correctly.
I also checked that it works using the command line.
I for some reason can't compile with any compiler at all.
Not even with VC++.
Is this a known issue?
Does anyone knows how to solve it?
This is the error I'm getting:

> "Static library - MinGW RELEASE" uses an invalid compiler. Skipping...
>   Nothing to be done.

Comment: anyone else? I'd like to know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:
I had to change the compiler name since the mingw distribution I downloaded saves the old GCC file names instead of mingw's ones. I wonder why code::blocks doesn't detect them as well.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to ask questions regarding Code::Blocks are the CB support forums at http://forums.codeblocks.org

Having said that - try this:

- start CB
- go to the Settings menu
- choose "Compiler & Debugger"
- navigate the tabbed dialog to "Toolchain Execurtables"
- select compiler/debugger directories & exes as appropriate